# .htaccess better rewriting solution ? why apache/nginx takes long time response

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After i added following rewriting code to the my website, i noticed that sever requests are taking a longtime, (i don't have any page html errors, js errors, or anything in my web site pages)

But i noticed that in firefox "loading" is keep on showing the page is still requesting and it takes a long time (1 min) to stop it.

I presume this rewriting code is creating this delay... any ideas on how to improve this ?

```
# BEGIN Rewrite
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^career.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.career.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^files/([^/]+)/seeker/cover/([^/]+)$ uploads/seeker/cover/$2  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^files/([^/]+)/seeker/cv/([^/]+)$ uploads/seeker/cv/$2  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^files/([^/]+)/account/([^/]+)$ uploads/account/$2  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^files/([^/]+)/employer/logo/([^/]+)$ uploads/employer/logo/$2  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^jobs/([^/]+)/?(.*)$ jobs.php?job_id=$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^industry/([^/]+)/?(.*)$ results.php?formID=industryBrowse&industry_id=$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^company/([^/]+)/?(.*)$ results.php?formID=employerBrowse&employer_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/employer/([^/]+)/?(.*)$ company.php?employer_id=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
# END Rewrite
```

Comment: turn on mod_rewrite debugging (`LogLevel`) and see what's going on under the hood. probably you've got a redirect loop occuring.

Comment: SO if you remove the rules, it doesn't take a minute to load a page? Are you sure it's any of those pages and not something one of the PHP files are doing?